# How to get the Time in UTC from Time & Timezone in PHP?

Tags: php, date, timezone, utc

I am working on an app which needs a certain functionality related to time & timezones.
Here is a pseudo code below which may provide brief about my doubt

```
$start_time = "10:00 AM"; // starting time of an event
$end_time = "11:00 AM"; // ending time of an event
$system_time = "1:30 AM";

$timezone = "India +5:30";
```

What I want is to show the status of the event as "Live" , "Upcoming" and "Finished" based on whether event is currently going on, is going to happen or has already happened.

How can I find this status independent of the timezone of the country ?

Any way In which I could have an universal function like

```
$universal_time = get_time_in_utc_for($system_time, $timezone); // similarly for start_time & end_time
```

Comment: See [`DateTime::setTimezone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good start - *use UTC*.

Traditionally [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is the method for the job. However, if you are using PHP > 5.3, you might find the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) class to be more flexible.

A quick code sample:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2013-03-28 10:00 AM +5:30');
// 1364445000
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using DateTime

```
<?
// Not sure where you're gonna run this
$b = PHP_EOL . "<br/>";

// Create your events in their natual start/end time per that country/TZ
$eventStartMyTime = '2013-03-28 11:30:00';
$eventEndMyTime = '2013-03-28 16:30:00';
$eventTimeZone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta');
$startTime = new DateTime($eventStartMyTime, $eventTimeZone);
$endTime = new DateTime($eventEndMyTime, $eventTimeZone);

// Now when the system deals with dates, it's going to
// deal with them all in UTC (DateTime object can do this)
// A Unix timestamp is inherently "in UTC"
// Store these values in a db if you need to
$startTS = $startTime->getTimestamp();
$endTS = $endTime->getTimestamp();

// Function to get status
function getStatus($dateTime, $start, $end) {

    // Get UTC timestamp for the input
    $time = $dateTime->getTimestamp();

    // Check against event times
    switch(true) {
        case $time >= $start && $time < $end: return "LIVE";
        case $time >= $end: return "ENDED";
        case $time <= $start: return "UPCOMING";
    }
}
```

### Testing

```
// Let's walk through some scenarios
$testUpcoming = new DateTime('2013-03-21 00:00:00', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
$testLive = new DateTime('2013-03-28 15:30:00', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
$testEnded = new DateTime('2013-03-28 23:30:00', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Calcutta'));
$testNewYork = new DateTime('2013-03-28 12:30:00', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$testPyongyang = new DateTime('2013-03-28 12:30:00', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Pyongyang'));

// Use a fixed TZ (the TZ of the server)
// Should be UPCOMING
echo getStatus($testUpcoming, $startTS, $endTS) . $b;
// Should be LIVE
echo getStatus($testLive, $startTS, $endTS) . $b;
// Should be ENDED
echo getStatus($testEnded, $startTS, $endTS) . $b;

// Pretend we're running on a server in New York
// Same timestamp, different TZ
// Should be ENDED
echo getStatus($testNewYork, $startTS, $endTS) . $b;

// Pretend we're running on a server in Pyongyang
// Same timestamp, different TZ
// Should be UPCOMING
echo getStatus($testPyongyang, $startTS, $endTS) . $b;


$now = new DateTime();
echo "Our current timezone is: " . $now->getTimezone()->getName()  . $b;
echo "And the event is: " . getStatus($now, $startTime, $endTime);
```